# Ruby Compare Very Large Files

Tags: amazon-s3

I have two CSV files that are lists of S3 bucket objects:

```
The first CSV file represents the objects in the source S3 bucket. 
The second CSV file represents the objects in the destination S3 bucket.
```

I need to know which files to copy from the source S3 bucket to the destination bucket by finding the objects that aren't already in the destination bucket. The lines of the CSV match path, size, and modified date. If any one of these is different I need the source object copied to the destination bucket.

Here's the first example CSV file:

```
folder1/sample/test1,55,2019-07-19 19:36:56 UTC
folder2/sample/test5,55,2019-07-19 19:34:31 UTC
folder3/sample/test9,55,2019-07-19 19:32:12 UTC
```

Here's the second example CSV file:

```
folder1/sample/test1,55,2019-07-16 19:32:58 UTC
folder2/sample/test5,55,2019-07-14 19:34:31 UTC
folder3/sample/test9,55,2019-07-19 19:32:12 UTC
```

In this example the first and second lines would be returned.

The following code works on these 3 liners but fails on randomly generated files 1000+ lines:

```
f1 = File.open('file1.csv', 'r')
f2 = File.open('file2.csv', 'r')

f1.each.zip(f2.each).each do |line1, line2|
  if line1 != line2
    puts line1
  end
end
```

How can I accurately compare all lines - preferably with the least amount of CPU/Memory overhead?

Answer (score 0):

You could load the destination list into an **array** in memory, then step through the source list one line at a time. If source line is not in the array, the file needs to be copied.

If even one file is too big to load into memory, and the files are sorted in filename order, then you could step through both files together and compare lines. You'll need to use the filenames to determine whether to skip over lines to stay in sync.

An alternative option is to use **Amazon Athena**, joining the data between files to find lines that don't match.